# Migrating Ionic 2 to Typescript 2.0 RC

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript2.0

Currently I'm using Ionic 2.0.0-beta.37. Which uses typescript 1.8.x . I'm attempting to us D3 version 4 with typescript, but the typings from [d3-v4-definitelytyped](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped) use Typescript 2.x. I'm getting compile errors on the typings and after putting in an issue on the [d3-v4-definitelytyped repo](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped/issues/115), I learned that I need to use TS 2.x in my Ionic 2 project.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index.d.ts(150,30): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index.d.ts(167,24): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index.d.ts(173,55): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-axis/index.d.ts(191,24): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-brush/index.d.ts(30,37): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-chord/index.d.ts(38,56): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-chord/index.d.ts(39,25): Error TS1110: Type expected.
TypeScript error: /Users/arash1/Projects/brite-front-end/node_modules/@types/d3-chord/index.d.ts(41,59): Error TS1110: Type expected.
```

I looked at my `package.json` file in my main IONIC directory and I don't see a `typescript` as a dependency, so I figure that it is using something else to define the version. I see:

- "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0"
- "tslint-ionic-rules": "^0.0.3"
- "tsify": "0.16.0"

So i went into `tslint-ionic-rules` and saw:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
```

Just to make an attempt I ran `npm install typescript@rc` to install the new version in `tslint-ionic-rules` `node_modules` to see if I get the same error. The error is still there.

Can some one offer guidance on how to do so? The RC was announced on the [MFST Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/08/30/announcing-typescript-2-0-rc/) recently.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, I didn't exactly solve the problem yet but I can at least explain what I've tried. 
To be exact I didn't use lint in my gulp.file but I did notice that ionic2 used browserify and when you look at the ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript module, you can see:

*tsifyOptions: {}*

You can use this to set the version of TS you'd like to use.

Example:

1. Install typescript 2.x locally
2. Add tsifyOptions: {} in your build task

It should look something like this:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function(done){
  runSequence(
    ['sass', 'html', 'fonts', 'scripts'],
    function(){
      buildBrowserify({
        minify: isRelease,
        browserifyOptions: {
          debug: !isRelease
        },
        uglifyOptions: {
          mangle: false
        },
        tsifyOptions: {
          typescript: require('your typescript')
        }
      }).on('end', done);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Plain and simply you can disable tslint all togheter from your gulp. After all tslint is just a collection of standarts